# Calculate 'next date' with different periods

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table called `checks`. This holds several periods.
For that checks have a `term` - like *each year*, *every 5 years* or *every 6 months*. They're all written as {number} {years/months/weeks}.

I need a query which gives me the check that is closest in the future from a given starting point in the past (or future).

The following gives me the `next_date`, but it works only once. If your start_date was on 2016/01/01, and you have a 6 month-check and a yearly check, you would always get a yearly check with the bottom solution, because 2017/01/01 is closest to now.

```
select `checks`.*,
IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(term, ' ', -1) = 'weeks', DATE_ADD('2016-01-01', INTERVAL SUBSTRING_INDEX(term, ' ', 1) week),
IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(term, ' ', -1) = 'months', DATE_ADD('2016-01-01', INTERVAL SUBSTRING_INDEX(term, ' ', 1) month), 
IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(term, ' ', -1) = 'years', DATE_ADD('2016-01-01', INTERVAL SUBSTRING_INDEX(term, ' ', 1) year), 0)))
as next_date from `checks`
```

In reality, at the time of writing it should give me the 6 months-check - Because that should happen on 06/01/2019, which is closest to my current date (2019/05/27).

Is there a way to determine this in a query?

Comment: (and this really does seem like a bad format)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really bad format, but I think you can do:

```
select c.*,
       (case when term like '% weeks'
             then date('2016-01-01') + interval (substring_index(term, -2) + 0) weeks
             when term like '% months'
             then date('2016-01-01') + interval (substring_index(term, -2) + 0) month
             when term like '% years'
             then date('2016-01-01') + interval (substring_index(term, -2) + 0) year
      end) as next_date 
from checks c
order by next_date asc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree format could use some improvement. However, this still would only give 2016/06/01 and 2017/01/01 as the next dates, not the (expected) 2019/06/01 and 2020/01/01.

Comment: @JoshuaW . . . Your question is asking for one row ("I need a query which gives me the check that is closest in the future from a given starting point in the past (or future).").  I don't understand where multiple values would be coming from.

Comment: The first one is indeed the one I need, however it needs to be the 6-months term. I misread your answer a bit and overlooked the `limit` part. Your query returns the 6-months term in any case. To be precise, if I run this query coming December, it should give the 1-year check back again.